# Loading gif when PHP form is processing

Tags: php

I have a PHP form which includes a file being uploaded upon submit. 
As I allow pretty big files, the page can often stand there loading for ages.

Is there a way to show the user a loading animation of some sort?

Comment: a javascript function that inserts the animation into the DOM, bound to the form's submit event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need JQuery to use my code, but it's worth it:

Put this script tag in your site `<head>`:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Put a hidden loading gif somewhere, wherever you want to see it

```
<img id="loader" src="loading.gif" />
```

Hide it on page load: `$('#loader').hide();`

Then in Javascript (or even better JQuery), inside your submit function...show/hide it:

```
function submit()
{
    $('#loader').show();
    // do your upload stuff
    $('#loader').hide();    
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea when submitting simple data, but how about submitting a pretty large file? How is it working across major browsers?

Comment: @Tadeck: PHP isn't an ideal platform for large file uploads. If there's any glitches in the upload, the entire portion already upload is most likely lost and non-resumable. But other than that, browsers won't really care if an upload is 1 byte or 50 gigabytes - if the browser can access the file, it can be uploaded.

Comment: @Marc I do not understand your answer. Sure, PHP has a lot of disadvantages and other languages are better when it comes to implementing specific features, but how is it related to my question about submitting user-entered textual data vs. submitting large files? The case was that you can not submit files through AJAX unless you use some Flash etc. This has nothing to do with server-side and you will probably hide spinning button (loader) before user uploads the file. This is weakness of above solution, not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I would put a hidden image somewhere on the page. Call a javascript function upon form submit, and let that function display the image, before submitting the form.